# Create separate ArrayList from Application variable in kotlin android

Tags: android, variables, kotlin, arraylist, copy

I'm trying to make a copy of `List<>` from a variable declared in Application class object. Problem for me is that I'm unable to make a separate copy. Any update which I do on second variable also updates the application variable. Below is the code I'm using:

```
var app: MyApplication
private var taskItems: ArrayList<TaskItem>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    app = applicationContext as MyApplication
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    taskItems = app.selectedTask?.items!!
}

fun updateCount(idx: Int, quantity: Int){
    taskItems?.get(idx)?.count = quantity
    // This updates both taskItems and app.selectedTask.items
    // I want to update only taskItems variable
}
```

I only want to update the `taskItems` variable from function *updateCount()* and not the app variable `app.selectedTask.items`. I've tried following changes in **onCreateView** function:

#### Try1:

```
taskItems= ArrayList<TaskItem>(app.selectedTask?.items!!)
```

#### Try2:

```
taskItems= ArrayList()
taskItems!!.addAll(app.selectedTask?.items!!)
```

#### Try3:

```
taskItems= ArrayList()
for (item in app.selectedTask?.items!!) {
    taskItems!!.add(item)
}
```

But none of the above code worked for me. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept the answer by clicking on ✓ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
taskItems= ArrayList()
app.selectedTask?.items!!.forEach {
    taskItems.add(it.copy())
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shafayat-hossain. Your solution worked. I had to change the updateCount() though, but that was a minor change.